# Putting focus in Html.ActionLink menu

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

My problem is this: I want a menu that clear the previous visited links (turning them to normal again), but keeping the link the current visited link as a:visited in css.

I have found a way to make this. But the problem is it is not working!! This is the code that I have:

```
< ul id="menuTop">
  < li id="menu-link-1">
    @Html.ActionLink("Home", "Index", null, null, new { id = "link-1-visited" })
  </li>
  < li id="menu-link-2">
    @Html.ActionLink("Produtos", "Products", null, null, new { id = "link-2-visited" })
  </li>

  < li id="menu-link-3">
    @Html.ActionLink("Fale Conosco", "ContactUs", null, null, new { id = "link-3-visited" })
  </li>

  < li id="menu-link-4">
    @Html.ActionLink("Quem Somos", "AboutUs", null, null, new { id = "link-4-visited" })
  </li>
< /ul>
```

This is my buttons, and the code to make them "visited" is that:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#link-1-visited').click(function() {
        $("#menu-link-1").removeAttr("menu-link-1");
        $(this).addClass('link-1-visited');
        window.alert("test 1 !!");
    });

    $('#link-2-visited').click(function() {
        $(this).addClass('link-1-visited');
        window.alert("test 2 !!");
    });

    $('#link-3-visited').click(function() {
        $(this).addClass('link-1-visited');
        window.alert("test 3 !!");
    });

    $('#link-4-visited').click(function() {
        $(this).addClass('link-1-visited');
        window.alert("test 4 !!");
    });
});
```

My code in css is:

```
ul#menuTop li#menu-link-1 a {
    background-image: url("../Content/images/Menu/menu-image-1-alt.png");
    margin-right: 1px;
}

ul#menuTop li#menu-link-1 a:hover {
    background-image: url("../Content/images/Menu/menu-image-1-hover.png");
    margin-right: 1px;
}

.link-1-visited {
    padding: 40px 20px 20px;
    border-width: 3px;
    border-bottom: 0px;
    border-style: solid;
    // more styles below...
}

ul#menuTop li a {
    border: 3px #98fb98 solid;
    border-bottom: 0px;
    //more styles below...
}

ul#menuTop li a:hover {
    padding: 40px 20px 20px;
    border-width: 3px;
    border-bottom: 0px;
    border-style: solid;
    //more styles below...
}
```

The problem is my code in menu-link-1 is not working. I want to remove the ul and li css and add class "link-1-visited" to it.

Do you have any ideas about how can I do that?

Comment: @ArunPJohny the actionlinks have the ids

Comment: @LucasBorsatto ARe you getting your alerts?

Comment: Yes, they pass normally. What can I do?

Answer (score 0):

```
$("#menu-link-1").removeAttr("menu-link-1");
```

What are you trying to do here?  menu-link-1 is not an attribute of the li, it is the id.  If you are trying to add and remove classes, just give it a class.

Comment: menu-link-1 is a id on css.

Comment: then you would want to do $("#menu-link-1").removeAttr("id","menu-link-1"); <--- Bad practice though to remove the id, you should be using classes instead

Answer (score 0):

try this... (switching `this` to `e.currentTarget` and passing e into function `function(e)`)

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('#link-1-visited').click(function(e)
  {
    $("#menu-link-1").removeAttr("id","menu-link-1");
    $(e.currentTarget).addClass('link-1-visited');
    window.alert("test 1 !!");
  });

  $('#link-2-visited').click(function(e)
  {
    $(e.currentTarget).addClass('link-1-visited');
    window.alert("test 2 !!");
  });

  $('#link-3-visited').click(function(e)
  {
    $(e.currentTarget).addClass('link-1-visited');
    window.alert("test 3 !!");
  });

  $('#link-4-visited').click(function(e)
  {
    $(e.currentTarget).addClass('link-1-visited');
    window.alert("test 4 !!");
  });
});
```

Comment: It is not working yet. I have tried by many ways, and none of that has worked. Is it not a problem in my code?

Comment: To explain it better: the action work well until I click in the Alert button, then it change to normal again. How to fix it? I use e.preventDefault(); to keep the change, but it is not working. Besides I need it change the page.