# How make a change focus menu in css/html/jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

My problem is simple: I want to make a menu like http://edition.cnn.com/

When I click in one of the buttons in menu, I want it get focus and the rest of them lose it.
This problem seems to be very easy, but I already tried by different ways and none of them work. Can you help me? How can I make this?

The other ways: [Putting focus in Html.ActionLink menu](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17667178/putting-focus-in-html-actionlink-menu/17691268?noredirect=1#17691268)

I want when I click in a button, when the page refresh it get the focus and the others keep normal or, if another button was selected, turn it normal.

Thanks for any sugestions.

Comment: Can you elaborate what you mean by focus?

Comment: Showing YOUR code is important - not someone else's.

Comment: do you mean `hover`? if so why dont you just look the source code?

Comment: *"I already tried by different ways and none of them work."* Can you show us what didn't work?

Comment: I have actualized the post to be more specific.

Comment: Based on your new link, this is sounding more like an ASP.NET MVC question. Is that what you're using? There's a lot of ways you can do this.

Comment: Yes, is MVC 3. Can you show it, please?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[FIDDLE DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/k8XL5/2/)

Hope this helps you!!!

```
$(function(){
    var jqMenu = $("#barre_menu").menu();

    $("#focus1").click(function(){
        try{
            jqMenu.menu( "focus", null, jqMenu.find("#azer"));
        }
        catch(exc){
            alert("Exception caught : "+exc);
        }
    });
    $("#focus2").click(function(){
        try{
            jqMenu.menu( "focus", null, jqMenu.find("#qsdf"));
        }
        catch(exc){
            alert("Exception caught : "+exc);
        }
    });
    $("#focus2").click(function(){
        try{
            jqMenu.menu( "focus", null, jqMenu.find("#wxcv"));
        }
        catch(exc){
            alert("Exception caught : "+exc);
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: This seems to be a little overkill for a simple menu.

Comment: And not an exception was left unhandled that day.

Comment: I have actualized the post to be more specific

Answer (score 1):

I might be wrong...but I think this is what you are getting at...

If you have your navigation menu in a list such as this:

```
<ul>
    <li><a href="default.asp">Home</a></li>
    <li><a href="news.asp">News</a></li>
    <li><a href="contact.asp">Contact</a></li>
    <li><a href="about.asp">About</a></li>
</ul>
```

You can apply styles to those links like this:

```
a:link {color:#FF0000;}      /* unvisited link */
a:visited {color:#00FF00;}  /* visited link */
a:hover {color:#FF00FF;}  /* mouse over link */
a:active {color:#0000FF;}  /* selected link */
```

Or if you want to change the style of the entire list item, you can do so like:

```
li {
    background-color: green;
}
```

Check out [W3 Schools](http://www.w3schools.com/css/css_link.asp) for more tutorials on styling links.

Comment: I have actualized the post to be more specific

Answer (score 1):

Your question is very vague, so while we all guess maybe you mean something like the following:

Html:

```
<nav>
    <ul>
        <li>Button 1</li>
        <li>Button 2</li>
        <li>Button 3</li>
    </ul>
</nav>
```

Javascript (you tagged jquery):

```
$(function() {
    $("nav ul li").click(function() {
        $("nav ul li").not(this).removeClass("active");
        $(this).addClass("active");
    });
});
```

CSS:

```
nav ul { list-style-type: none; }
nav ul li { float: left; cursor: pointer; padding: 10px; background-color: #eee; }
nav ul li.active { background-color: red; color: white; }
nav ul li:hover:not(.active) { background-color: #ccc; }
```

See the fiddle here: http://jsfiddle.net/6UdkD/1/

Comment: I have actualized the post to be more specific